# Spring cloud gateway + keycloak is returning 404 (not found)

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, postman, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm setting up a microservice architecture using spring boot. Hence I have a microservice "poc-be", an "api-gateway" and a running instance of Keycloak for managing authentication and authorization.
I searched a lot and I've followed various examples, but I'm still getting a 404 error when calling the service through the api-gateway.
**Keycloak**
keycloak is running on localhost:8080, I created a realm, a client, an user and a role:
[image]

Using Postman, I can obtain an access token calling http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/my_realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
[image: Postman call for getting access token]

I would use this jwt token for making another call to the api-gateway for accessing protected service.
**API gateway**
The api gateway project has the following relevant dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>11.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
      <!-- Gateway functionality -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- keycloak Spring Boot Adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I setup this configuration in application-dev.yml

```
server:
  port: 8082
cluster:
  uri-local-be: http://localhost:8083
keycloak:
  enabled: true
  realm: my_realm
  # The value we specify in keycloak.resource matches the client we named in the admin console
  resource: niuma-services
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  bearer-only: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
  public-client: true
spring:
  ...
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: protected
          uri: ${cluster.uri-local-be}
          predicates:
          - Path=/api/hello/*
```

You can see the route for addressing the service (no service discovery at the time).
I implemented a SecurityConfig class, as found on tutorials:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        log.info("SecurityConfig.configureGlobal");
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        log.info("SecurityConfig.KeycloakConfigResolver");
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        log.info("SecurityConfig.sessionAuthenticationStrategy");
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("SecurityConfig.configure");
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spi*").hasRole("user").anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer() {
        return ServerCodecConfigurer.create();
    }
```

The microservice it's exposing an endpoint at localhost:8083/api/hello/secure returning a simple string.
I achieved the desired behavior when calling directly localhost:8083/api/hello/secure/ :
- unhauthorized when calling without access token
- successfully respond when calling with access token

But I can't get the api gateway working with both the service and keycloak.
If I call localhost:**8082**/api/hello/secure passing the access token as Authorization header, I get a 404 and I can't understand why:
[image: 404 api gateway]

Reading the logs I see the authentication process occurs, but I can't explain the 404:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /error at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@7102dd3c: Authentication: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.token.KeycloakAuthenticationToken@7102dd3c: Principal: ciro; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.account.SimpleKeycloakAccount@42a60ed1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_offline_access, ROLE_user, ROLE_uma_authorization'
...
o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/sso/login']
o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/sso/login'
...
f.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Attempting Keycloak authentication
o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
...
o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : successful authorized
o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : User 'ciro' invoking 'http://localhost:8082/error' on client 'niuma-services'
...
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}, headers={masked} in DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
...
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404, headers={masked}
...
```

Hoping I reported all information needed, I would ask some help getting authentication working using access token obtained from keycloak, calling the api gateway.

Comment: Did you resolved this issue ?

Comment: In my case I was getting error because I configured wrong auth url. The correct url should be 'keycloak.auth-server-url: http://localhost:XXXX/auth'.

Comment: Did your issue resolved? Even I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, as shown on application start log, spring MVC is not compatible with Spring Cloud Gateway right now (version Hoxton.SR8), this is the message on log:

> Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud
> Gateway at this time. Please remove spring-boot-starter-web
> dependency.

Your dependency *keycloak-spring-boot-starter* includes *spring-boot-starter-web*

Answer (score 0):

We finally resolved using the following setup. I didn't fix the problem (someone else worked on it) but I will try to share our current setup:

MICROSERVICE SECURITY DEPENDENCIES (inherited from a shared lib)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Resource Server support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- support for decoding and verifying JWTs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Keycloak Admin REST Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>18.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

ALL MICROSERVICES have in common the following pom

```
<properties>
    <groupId>my.org</groupId>
    <java.version>17</java.version>

    <spring.boot.version>2.6.7</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.cloud-version>2021.0.2</spring.cloud-version>
    <k8s.version>1.1.8.RELEASE</k8s.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.rabbitmq</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-rabbitmq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    // other deps
</dependencies>
```

API-GATEWAY POM

```
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.org</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${parent.dependencies.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Gateway functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Netflix library Hystrix implements the circuit breaker pattern -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Each microservice has the following configuration class:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Autowired
    private TenantSecurityProperties tenantProperties;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, @Value("${contextpath}") String contextPath) {
    
        var authenticationManagerResolver = new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(
                tenantProperties.getIssuerList(),
                new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()));
    
        http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(contextPath + ... + "/**")
            .hasRole(ROLE)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(new HttpStatusServerAccessDeniedHandler(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer
                    .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));

        return http.build();
    }
    
    private static JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        // Convert realm_access.roles claims to granted authorities, for use in access decisions
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new KeycloakRealmRoleConverter());
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }
}
```

And the following application definition

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class }, 
        scanBasePackages = { "my.org.my.app", "my.org.security"})
public class MyApplication {
```

Each microservices has these application properties/configmap:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        kubernetes:
          config:
            name: my-app
            namespace: default
            #Enable Secrets PropertySource
            enabled: true
      security:
        oauth2:
          resourceserver:
            jwt:
              jwk-set-uri: http://192.168.10.201:30444/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Keycloak client configuration:
[image: keycloak gateway client]

[image: client configuration]

I hope to be of help to someone else